# Image used as pattern in inline SVG has greenish tint

Tags: svg, colors

I have this inline SVG element. Some of its sub elements use image patterns. (In the attached photo, the SVG object is on the left and the image with correct color is on the right). A very strange greenish hue is affecting all image patterns and images in the SVG which have patches of white in the original images used.  What could be the reason?  I've already checked this both in Firefox and Chrome. Same problem shows in both browsers. I used SVG transforms (rotate, scale, translate) to manipulate the images but never a command to change the colors..
[image]

EDIT 2017-09-24 (screenshot in Safari) - Safari displays the correct color
[image]

Comment: Does the color change when you play around with browser enlargement? Or when you change the size the pattern is shown at?

Comment: The hue stays there even if zoom in and out on the browser.  Also when i change the size of the pattern. But I just wondered if it would show in Safari and to my surprise it does not!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can see and experiment in our own browsers.